# HTML table add header to each row

Tags: html

I want to create a table like

```
col1 | col2 | col3
**     **     **
col4 
****************
```

How should I write the html table tag?

Thank you so much

Comment: `<table></table>` is the table tag

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
   <td>col3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>**</td>
  <td>**</td>
  <td>**</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">col4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">*********</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way - add a column Span to the merged.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>*</th>
    <th>*</th>
    <th>*</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">***</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lde2fwe7/

Comment: The best way would use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, too.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9p0e1fz/)

use `colspan`  can achieve it.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="3">head</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>**</td>
    <td>**</td>
    <td>**</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">col4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"> your text*</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```